# Copying keyframes from one project/rig to another

Tags: rigging, armature, keyframes

How do you go about copying the keyframes from one project/rig/object to another. Baring in mind, that my rigs are in totally different saved files. The character I'm working on is basically the same as my other, except the character has been modified - squashed inwards so they're thinner, characteristics altered/added etc. So it uses the same armature as well. However, though I did delete it at the start, I'd like to transfer my first character's walk animation to my second just to see what it's like, alter it, and save time. I have read you're supposed to select the object, hold Shift, select the armature, press Ctrl + L and then select 'Animation Data'...? I can't find this option anywhere. I've also tried selecting all the keyframes from one rig, copying them, and then pasting them into the new one, but it doesn't work. How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can always append your old armature and/or actions into the new file. (Shift F1)

Comment: Didn't think of that. Will give that a try now. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be doing anything; it doesn't appear in my current scene, or if I start a new one.

Comment: Importing individual animations seems to work though, so there's that. :)

Comment: You should be able to import the whole model including all it's animation strips that are in the Dopesheet so I'll ask the obvious - have you copy pasted the model into the new project from the appended scene? (CTL-C & CTL-V)

Comment: It’s not the entire model and its animations I was after though - just the keyframes or a single animation. But appending individual animations works for me. :)

Comment: Actually, I had in mind that you'd delete the appended model and scene once you've copied the anim strips across to the new project's model.  You've got it sorted anyway, so that's always good.